# conditional time compare

Tags: php

I'm using this within my sql code to record the time

```
`dt` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Output example : `2012-03-15 19:51:07`

**Question 1** what i want to do is to compare between time recoreded before and the time at certain moment.

```
$tr = "2012-03-15 19:51:07"; // time recorded
```

and

```
$tn = "2012-03-16 8:33:23"; // time now
```

so that i can say

```
if ($tn > $tr){
echo "something";
}else{
echo "something else";
}
```

**Question 2** what if i wanna say if `$tn > $tr` by certain exact number of hours (example 3 hours) show something and else show something else. (conditional compare)

so can we really compare time ! ~thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare the times you can use `strtotime()`

```
if (strtotime($tn) > strtotime($tr)) {
    echo "something";
} else {
    echo "something else";
}
```

`strtotime()` will give you the time in seconds.  You could then subtract one from the other to get the number of seconds between the time recorded and the time now:

```
 $diff = strtotime($tn) - strtotime($tr);
```

Getting the number of hours is then just a matter of arithmetic.

```
$hours = floor($diff/3600);
```